# Барбекю и барбекью - в чем разница?

Tags: орфография, этимология

В последние годы чаще всего можно встретить слово "барбекю" именно в таком написании, но мне приходилось видеть и вариант "барбекью", правда, очень редко. Сайт "грамота.ру" на запрос "барбекью" дает ответ: "Искомое слово отсутствует. Похожее слово:барбекю". В чем разница?

Comment: Первый раз вижу такое название, всегда думала: барбекю - правильное написание. Но вот на упаковке увидела - барбекью. [фото упаковки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekgrz.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я совсем плохо знаю французский, но сильно сомневаюсь, что здесь возможно произношению "кью". А само по себе различие в написании заимствованных слов меня ничуть не удивляет.
~ ~ ~ 
Короче, посмотрел все, что было доступно.
Французские слова (включая имена собственные) заимствуются пости исключительно с кю, английские - с кью, как это и принято в языках-источниках.

Comment: http://ru.forvo.com/word/barbecue/ дает ˈbɑːbɪkjuː, так что все-таки кью.

Comment: Нету там никакого "кью". 
Даже гугл не даёт. "КЮ" с энергичным придыханием, как и положено во французском. Ну не может там йот появиться, его вообще нет во французском.

Answer (score 8):

А есть еще и такой вариант))))))))))))

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не загромождать формулировку вопроса, попытаюсь высказать свое мнение. На основе анализа примеров употребления этих слов в речевой практике можно прийти к выводу (правда, очень неуверенному), что "барбекю" - это соответствующим способом приготовленное блюдо, а "барбекью" - мероприятие типа пикника, на котором главным блюдом является "барбекю". Вот такое умозаключение, в котором я и сам сомневаюсь. Может быть, кто-то из коллег знает более убедительный и вразумительный ответ на этот вопрос?

Comment: Я не слышала слова "барбекью". По-моему, здесь просто проблемы транслитерации, которая еще не установилась окончательно.  

Поиск слова _барбекью_ дал гораздо меньше результатов, и в основном это слово относилось к __прибору для жарки__

Comment: А вот скажите-ка мне такую вещь: должна ли быть разница в произношении между "барбекю" и "барбекью"? Мне кажется да, т.к. в последнем случае ь имеет именно разделительную роль.

Comment: Если не ориентироваться на исходное произношение, а просто прочитать написанное - разница будет.

Comment: А как ближе к оригиналу?

Comment: Загнала английский вариант "barbecue" в переводчик Google и включила произношение. Ясно слышится "барбекью". По-французски написание такое же, но произношение не знаю (в гугле только немецкий)

Comment: В Википедии нашел кое-что о происхождении этого слова. Я не "француз", поэтому не уверен в правильности произношения слова, но похоже, что там есть "кью":
"Согласно одной из любительских теории, слово происходит от фр. barbe à queue, дословно означающего "от бороды до хвоста". Во время путешествий на кораблях раньше брали с собой коз, которые жарились, будучи нанизанными. Впрочем, большинство языковедов считают эту этимологию ложной

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, не нужно в русском языке это *барбекью*. Пусть в английском или французском звучит, как там принято, а по-русски естественно (адаптированно) *барбекю*. И все, не надо лишний раз создавать сложности. И пусть хоть все понятия, связанные с *барбекю* (мероприятие, решетки...), войдут в список значений этого же слова. Как в английском: одно слово и к нему 20 значений. Но из контекста все равно все ясно. Другое дело, что русскому, к сожалению, не свойственно развитие в сторону упрощения правил. Нет же, появляются все новые слова, очень похожие друг на друга, но при этом мало кто знает точно, как же правильно называть вещи своими именами. В итоге - большинство невежды...

Comment: Я лично вижу несправедливость. Много ли слов в русском языке, содержащих "кю"? А "кью"? Вот, например, с "кью" однозначно пишутся [Фортескью][1] и [секьюрити][2]. И почему-то никому в голову не приходит их писать по-другому.

 [1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%8C%D1%8E
 [2]:http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%F1%E5%EA%FC%FE%F0%E8%F2%E8&all=x

Comment: @__inna__,   
вы очень сильно ошибаетесь, есди думаете, что "кю" - это что-то свойственное русскому языку. Таких слов в русском - раз, два и обчелся. Мягкое к перед гласными переднего ряда - это совсем не русский. 
- - - 
@gecube,  
екьюрити - это из английского, не аргумент. "Кью" действительно тоже редкость в русском, но как ни странно это просто факт, который не из чего не следует, такое сочетание ничем русской фонетике не противоречит.

Comment: Но почему-то ведь "барбекю" закрепилось в словарях, а "-кью" нет (поправьте меня, если это не так). Просто думаю, это тот случай, когда можно доверять литературной норме. Звучит вполне естественно и без дополнительного звука "й". А вводить в речь еще одно слово "барбекью" с отличным значением считаю сомнительной идеей.

Comment: > Но почему-то ведь "барбекю" закрепилось в словарях, а "-кью" нет  
  
Странно было бы ожидать другого. Не сомневаюсь, что слово пришло из французского, дне никакого "-кью" нет, в чем легко убедиться хотя бы из гугловского переводчика.

Comment: С огромным интересом прочитал все написанное в ответ на мой вопрос. Большое спасибо всем! (Кстати, когда набирал здесь первое предложение, вначале после слова "все" поставил запятую, а потом вспомнил, что причастный оборот, стоящий после определительного местоимения, не обособляется. Но где я это читал?)

Comment: Т.е. итого Вы предполагаете, что барбекю имеет французское происхождение? А как-нибудь проследить или аргументировать это мнение возможно?

> А вводить в речь еще одно слово "барбекью" с отличным значением считаю сомнительной идеей.

Соглашусь, вводить новое слово бессмысленно. Должен остаться только один (с) "Горец".

Comment: "Т.е. итого Вы предполагаете, что барбекю имеет французское происхождение? А как-нибудь проследить или аргументировать это мнение возможно?"   
Хотя бы то, что ударение на последнем слоге: барбекЮ. Это уже характерно для французского, а не английского.

Comment: Не соглашусь по той причине, что хоть ударение в русском свободное, но оно могло запросто переместиться.